# Ebean partially not saving ManyToOne association

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.0, ebean

### PREAMBLE

I am struggling with a very strange problem.
I am trying to create an "web application boostrap" procedure - run app, fill in the initial db, do some enhancements, and be ready to serve.

I have a table with 40000+ records of Stuff.
I have a table with 10000+ records of Instruction.

Each stuff item has an instruction. -> Stuff-Instruction is ManyToOne relationship.

The steps of my application startup are:

1. Fill in Stuff items, but do not initialize their instruction.
2. Fill in all the instructions
3. Try to associate stuff with instructions

Now how I do the step 3:

```
public class AssociateJob {

//TODO - !! there are some gaps in processing! Why??
private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 100;

/**
 * Best effort to associate stuff and instructions
 *
 * @return count of orphaned (instruction == null) stuffs
 */
public int associate() {
    PagingList<Stuff> stuffs = Stuff.find.findPagingList(PAGE_SIZE);
    return processPagingList(stuffs);
}



private int processPagingList(PagingList<Stuff> pages) {
    int countNull = 0;
    for (int page = 0; page < pages.getTotalPageCount(); page++) {
        Page<Stuff> stuffsPage = pages.getPage(page);
        countNull += processPage(stuffsPage);
    }
    return countNull;
}

private int processPage(Page<Stuff> stuffsPage) {
    List<Stuff> list = stuffsPage.getList();
    return processList(list);

}

private int processList(List<Stuff> list) {
    int countNull = 0;
    EbeanServer server = Ebean.getServer(null);

    Transaction tx = beginTransaction();
    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<>();
    fields.add("instruction");

    for (Stuff d : list) {
        Instruction i = Instruction.byNameAndForm(d.name, d.form);
        if (i == null) {
            countNull++;
            continue;
        }
        d.instruction = i;
        server.update(d, fields, tx);

    }
    commit(tx);
    return countNull;
}


private Transaction beginTransaction() {
    EbeanServer server = Ebean.getServer(null);

    Transaction transaction = server.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setBatchSize(100);
    transaction.setPersistCascade(false);
    return transaction;

}

private void commit(Transaction transaction) {
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

When the **step 3** is complete, the AssociateJob.associate() method returns 6 - 6 stuff items are left without the instruction, so I'll have to specify it later manually.

### PROBLEM

In fact, the are many associations that are left unsaved.
When I execute:

```
int countNull = Stuff.find.where().eq("instruction", null).findRowCount();
```

I receive **over 12 000** stuff items without instruction.

### QUESTION

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

For now I am sticking with a temporal crunchy  workaround (creating another job to associate stuff with `stuff.instruction == null`), but that is very bad, and this possibly-Ebean-issue is going to affect my future internal processess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Rob's hint here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ebean/Gfx77JnqgGc/qfN8b7OyrqAJ), I came to a very simple and elegant solution of the problem:

```
public class AssociateJob {


    public int associate() {

        String sql = 
           "UPDATE stuff AS s SET instruction_id = " + 
           "(SELECT i.id FROM instruction AS i WHERE " + 
           "i.name LIKE s.name AND i.form LIKE s.form )" +
           " WHERE instruction_id IS NULL";

        SqlUpdate update = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(sql);

        return update.execute();

    }


}
```

So the whole batch processing could be done via one large update operation, the way I didn't think of, blinded by elegance of object-oriented approach of ORM.